# Example of a birational morphism on projective plane that is not an isomorphism of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is there a birational morphism $P^2\to P^2$ (over $\Bbb C$) that is not an isomorphism of schemes? This was a past exam question in algebraic geometry, to prove or disprove the statement. I first tried to prove it, but I got stuck. Now I am expecting of a counterexample, which I cannot find.. Any hints?

Comment: Approximately what technology are you expecting to solve this with? For instance, there is a famous theorem that every birational morphism between smooth projective surfaces is composition of blowdowns to points which resolves your question, but this might be a little past what you have available to you.

Comment: @KReiser My class is using the book of Hulek's Elementary Algebraic Geometry, so it seems any technology in this book is available.

Comment: Try the map given by $(xy,yz,zx)$.

Comment: As it seems there are differing interpretations in the comments, let's clear it up: do you mean for your map to be a morphism of schemes (everywhere-defined), or do you allow rational maps (not necessarily defined everywhere)?

Comment: @KReiser It is not necessarily defined everywhere, following Hulek's book. I should make a clarification earlier..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the Zariski open subset $U\subset \mathbb P^2_\mathbb C$ defined by the simultaneous inequations $x\neq0,y\neq0,z\neq 0$.
It admits of the *regular* automorphism $$f:U \stackrel {\cong}{\to} U:[x:y:z]\mapsto [\frac 1x:\frac 1y:\frac 1z]$$ which can be seen as the required birational automorphism of $\mathbb P^2_\mathbb C$.
As an optional complement we might like to know the maximal domain to which $f$ be regularly extended.
Answer: it is the open subset $V=\mathbb P^2_\mathbb C \setminus \{[0:0:1],[0:1:0],[1:0:0]\}$
The maximal extension of $f$ is the *morphism*  $$\hat f:V\to \mathbb P^2_\mathbb C:[x:y:z]\mapsto [yz:zx:xy]$$ Beware that $\hat f$ is not an automorphism of $V$ since its image is not included in $V$ : for example $\hat f([0:1:1]=[1:0:0]\notin V$.